# Using RegExp with a built string parameter returning null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match and extract the function prototype from source code. The regex that I am using works perfectly on regex10.com, but when I try the below code, I get null.

The variable `functionName` is actually derived while looping and is obtained from a different process, but I've included it as a constant below for testing.

```js
const data = "\n" +
"//:SEFUN tail\n" +
"//\n" +
"//Reads the last `num_lines` number of lines from `file` and returns as a\n" +
"//string.\n" +
"//\n" +
"//This sefun is not compatible with old-style efun::tail() as 1) it accepts\n" +
"//a second argument of the number of lines, and 2) it returns a string rather\n" +
"//than printing out the results. \n" +
"varargs string tail(string file, int num_lines)\n" +
"{\n" +
"    int size, max, length ;\n" +
"    string data ;\n" +
"\n" +
"    // Mandatory\n" +
"    if( nullp( file ) ) error(\"tail() : No file name passed.\n\") ;\n" ;

const functionName = "tail"

// let's find the prototype
const regexString = `^[\\w\\s]*\\s*${functionName}\\s*\\(.*\\)$`
const funcRegex = new RegExp( regexString )
const regexResults = funcRegex.exec( data )

console.log(`regexString ${regexString}`)
console.log(`regexResults: ${regexResults}`)

// "regexString ^[\w\s]*\s*tail\s*\(.*\)$"
// "regexResults: null"
```

It should find `varargs string tail(string file, int num_lines)`. I'm always having problems with Regex and I hope someone can help. Thank you in advance.

Just to be complete, this is the regex101.com that works: `^[\w\s]*\s*tail\s*\(.*\)$`.

Comment: You are using an anchor, pass the `m` for multiline as the second argument to the RegExp constructor like `const funcRegex = new RegExp( regexString, "m" )`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: Also, if you make this a separate comment, I will mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test the regex at regex101, you can see the default options:

[image]

You have to add the `m` modifier to the constructor:

```
const funcRegex = new RegExp( regexString, "m" )
```

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline):

> The "m" flag indicates that a multiline input string should be treated as multiple lines. For example, if "m" is used, "^" and "$" change from matching at only the start or end of the entire string to the start or end of any line within the string.